# Higher Order Function Python (never ending?)

Tags: python, loops, recursion, higher-order-functions

I have a code that works when it's input with an increasing value like '123' but not when the next character is smaller than the previous character (eg. '132') and if there's a same number, the recursion never stops (eg. '122')

Please kindly point out the issue in my code and a solution would be appreciated greatly.

```
def sum(term, a, next, b):
    if (a > b):
        return 0
    else:
        print (term(a), a, next(a), b)
        return term(a) + sum(term, next(a), next, b)

def knocked_down(game):

    t1 = lambda x:int(game[x])
    t2 = 0
    t3 = lambda x: int(game[x])
    t4 = len(game)-1
    return sum(t1, t2, t3, t4)

results=knocked_down("123")
print('---')
print(results)
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do when it does work?

Comment: @Sayse It's suppose to do '1+2+3' and you print out 6.

Comment: By the way, you should avoid overriding built-in names. In this case, `next` is bad name for parameter.

Comment: @BoseongChoi I understand. The sum() function wasn't written by me. I was tasked to use it and I'm not allowed to change the code. (btw this isn't homework or a work project)

Comment: Are you looking for `sum(map(int,"123"))`?

Comment: I think that something is wrong about `t3` function. I think that `t3` should be `lambda x: x + 1`.

Comment: So, you're supposed to provide the correct input for `sum` so it behaves like adding 1+2+3 together? And this *isn't* homework or some other artificial test?

Comment: @BoseongChoi i tried that, and it'll go out of range (IndexError: string index out of range)

Comment: @deceze Well I'm serving the military and with my free time I want to practice coding so I took a coding task from a friend who's in university and I'm trying to learn and improve my coding skills. *sheesh*

Comment: @Shawn I ran my code in my answer, and it works. Can you show me what data causes the error?

Comment: @BoseongChoi OMG alright my mistake. I changed t3 = lambda x:int(game[x+1]) instead of lambda x: x + 1

Comment: @BoseongChoi Thank you so much! My code is working as it should. I've been staring at this for wayy too long and I think my overthinking and confusion made me miss a simple mistake. Appreciate your time sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sum` function, the parameters might mean

- `term`: Function to get value by index
- `a`: Start index
- `next`: Function to get next index
- `b`: Last index

And OP said:

> The `sum()` function wasn't written by me. I was tasked to use it and I'm not allowed to change the code.

So I didn't touch `sum` function.
You can change `t3` into `lambda x: x + 1`.

```py
def sum(term, a, next, b):
    if (a > b):
        return 0
    else:
        print(term(a), a, next(a), b)
        return term(a) + sum(term, next(a), next, b)


def knocked_down(game):
    t1 = lambda x: int(game[x])
    t2 = 0
    t3 = lambda x: x + 1
    t4 = len(game) - 1
    return sum(t1, t2, t3, t4)


results = knocked_down("132")
print('---')
print(results)
```

output:

```
1 0 1 2
3 1 2 2
2 2 3 2
---
6
```